# Convert SOAP 1.2 to SOAP 1.1

Tags: web-services, soap

I have a SOAP message in version 1.2. How can I convert it to version 1.1 since my server only support version 1.1?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://myexample.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soapenc12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
xmlns:tns="http://myexample.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://myexample.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soapenc12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:tns="http://myexample.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xsd:element name="Result" type="tns:Result" />
      .
      .
      .
      .
      </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="ValidateBill">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:ValidateBillServicesHttpBinding" name="ValidateBillServicesHttpPort">
          <soap12:address location="http://123.456.78:8080/ValidateBill" />
        </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My info provided may be too little since I don't know much about SOAP. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hi @YWah were you able to find a solution for this? Can you update the answer if you did please. Cheers!